# Display only last three items of a tcl list

Tags: tcl

I currently iterate through a tcl list using the following way

```
foreach  i  $listname  {
    puts $i
}
```

How could I only display the last three items of a list ?
In c++ I would do something like this

```
for( int i = listname.size()-1; i>=0;i--)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would do your c loop in tcl.

test.tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set mylist [list Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet]
set length [llength $mylist]
set stopat [expr $length - 3]

for {set i [expr $length - 1]} {$i >= $stopat} {incr i -1} {
        puts [lindex $mylist $i]
}
```

Output:

```
./test.tcl
Violet
Indigo
Blue
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do an analogous thing in Tcl. You can use `llength` to determine the number of items in the list and then set up a `for` loop with a counter variable and use `lindex` to fetch the items you are interested in.

Off the top of my head I would instead write:

```
foreach item [lrange $listname end-2 end] {
    puts $item
}
```

This uses `lrange` to make a new list that is part of another list and uses the fact that indices given to `lrange` can be symbolic and have simple arithmetic in them to select the list elements that you want.